# Android broadcast receiver and intent filter

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I am new to android platform.please help me out how the Broadcast Receiver and Intent Filter behaves in android.
Is there any other way to broadcast other than

```
public class OutGoingBrodcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.err.println("OUTGOING");
            Intent i=new Intent();
            i.setAction("com.ith.OUT");
            context.sendBroadcast(i);

        }

    }
```

to receive broadcast in

```
    public class IncomingBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(intent.getAction().equals("com.ith.OUT")){
                System.out.println("hit INCOMING");
            }
        }

    }
```

mainfest

```
<receiver android:name=".OutgoingReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name=".IncomingReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.ith.OUT"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

i want to know is there any other way to broadcast other than

```
Intent i=new Intent();
i.setAction("com.ith.OUT");
context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

using custom intent filter like `com.ith.OUT`

Comment: What do you mean by "any other way"? What sort of ways do you want to broadcast / receive it?

Comment: i mean use custom filter but want to broadcast out from the application. eg when change occure in Log file